# No se modifican los cambios al editar bootstrap.min.css

Tags: java, css, html5, bootstrap, jsp

soy novato con bootstrap! estoy diseñando una pagina web con java (utilizo IDE eclipse oxygen y TomCat v8.5, aclaro por las dudas) fui a la pagina de bootstrap copie el código de esta nav [aca el link de la nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/) en el navegador se me visualiza perfectamente, el problema es que:

1)Quiero cambiar los colores como por ejemplo el fondo de esa nav, entonces fui a la carpeta css, abrí el archivo bootstrap.min.css, busque el nombre de la clase de esa nav, le cambie el color y como resultado Desde Eclipse se me ve el cambio al hacer correr el jsp, pero cuando lo pruebo desde el navegador google o cualquiera que sea, no me muestra el nuevo cambio de color.

2)Ademas Al hacer click en el dropDown no hace el drop!.

Espero sea haya entendido!

Comment: Podrías añadir los cambios que le hiciste? algo de código seria útil para ayudarte.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder..mira en realidad no hice cambios solo fui al css y me fije el color de fondo que tenia por default esat es la clase .bg-light{background-color:#f8f9fa!important}

Comment: revisa toda la documentación acá esta la documentacion del background https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#color-schemes

Comment: Muchas Gracias David!! voy a leer!

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar de una manera mas cómoda te recomiendo usar la versión desminificada para realizar tus cambios. Tener en cuenta que los componentes como los DropDowns requieren tener el archivo js en tu proyecto.

Respecto al los estilos verifica que la ruta este correcta cuando estés en el navegador, Si pudieras agregar una captura de la consola de Chrome seria mucho mejor

Comment: aca inspeccionar desde el navegador chrome https://i.gyazo.com/8b2c34293b287932f256e376abcc3bcf.png

Comment: De la consola por favor.

Comment: Perdón la demora Thomas a esto te referís? https://i.gyazo.com/000c0e9681ee101fbf6522e1c60c7a83.png

Comment: @Claudio en tu primera imagen veo que se está aplicando correctamente el color, ¿qué es lo que deseas entonces?

Comment: Gracias por responder Jheyman, que raro no se me visualizaba el cambio en el Chrome y con respecto al DropDown para que funcione tuve que cambiar los scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto al color de la nav, le hice caso a David Santos siguiendo esto [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#color-schemes) Solo que me da a elegir entre esos colores, yo quería otros. Y con respecto al DropDown la solución fue cambiar los scripts por estos:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```